# Generating Gif from Mp4 directly - ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif, animated-gif, shell-exec

I am trying to generate a gif from an mp4 video file. I want to scale it and crop it while generating.

I achieved that (cropping & scaling) from *mp4 to mp4* with the below line , (so I can extract pngs with ffmpeg and use Imagick to make animated gif), but I believe there is a better way of achieving purely with ffmpeg.

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "scale=300:ih*300/iw, crop=200:500:50:80" -c:a copy out.mp4`

*My question is how to achieve the same this code is doing, but for directly generating gif from mp4.*

---

Then I started tweaking with mp4 to gif conversion, but when palette comes in, I couldn't fully understand what's going on.

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/556031) and I made it work, however I couldn't understand how to adapt scaling & cropping.

`$ ffmpeg -y -ss 30 -t 3 -i in.mp4 \
-vf fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen palette.png`

`$ ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 3 -i in.flv -i palette.png -filter_complex \ "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" out.gif`

I partially understand what this bit does `-y -ss 30 -t 3 -i in.mp4` (getting the first 30 seconds and generating a 3 second gif out of it). But for the next lines, I am completely lost what it is actually doing.

It'd be amazing if someone can explain what each command does, or refer a link explaining this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first command,

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 30 -t 3 -i in.mp4 \
-vf fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen palette.png
```

`-y` causes ffmpeg to overwrite if output file already exists, so no prompt for confirmation.

`-vf`, alias for `-filter:v`, is a video filterchain, which takes one video input and processes each specified filter successively. So input -> filter 1 -> filter 2 ... -> filter n -> filter output

`fps=10` converts the source to this framerate by dropping or duplicating frames as needed, no interpolation performed. If your source is 20 fps, this will drop every other frame. If it's 5 fps, it will duplicate every frame once.

`scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos` resizes the video to a width of 320 pixels and the height to a length so that the original aspect ratio is maintained. If you wanted to resize to 320x300, you would replace the `-1` with `300`. Lanczos is the scaling algorithm used. See list [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Scaler-Options). Lanczos is good.

`palettegen` generates a 256 color palette of the entire input stream. Usually used in conjunction with paletteuse.

The `-filter_complex` in your second command is when you have to apply filters to multiple inputs and/or need to generate multiple outputs. A bit long to summarize here, see [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Filtering).